# How to pass more than one value using anchor tag

Tags: asp.net

```
<a class="lbOn" 
       href="viewlogin.aspx?pagename=articledisplayview.aspx">post
            <asp:LinkButton 
                ID="lnk_login" 
                runat="server" 
                Font-Names="Arial" 
                Font-Size="12pt"
                ForeColor="DimGray"  
                Visible="False">PostComments</asp:LinkButton>
</a>
```

if user is not login befor posting comments he is redirected to loginpage.but i want to also
send a slno or session to loginpage to get back to the same articledispalayviewpage.
i don't know how to send  more than one value in anchortag

Thank's inadvance

Comment: A `LinkButton` inside an `<a>` - why?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want but you can add extra parameters to to the URL like this -

```
href="viewlogin.aspx?pagename=articledisplayview.aspx&arg1=1&arg2=2">
```

Use `?` after the page name then the name/value pair of the first parameters , all subsequent parameters should appended with `&`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this 
`ahref="http://contoso.com/products.aspx?field1=value1&field2=value2"` as mentioned here
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw.aspx